# Hasura on Google Cloud Run - Monitoring

Tags: google-cloud-platform, graphql, monitoring, google-cloud-run, hasura

I would like to have a monitoring on my Hasura API on Google Cloud Run. Actually I'm using the monitoring of Google Cloud but It is not really perfect. I have the count of 200 code request. But I want for example, the number of each query / mutation endpoint request.

I want :

```
count 123 : /graphql/user
count 234 :/graphql/profil
```

I have :

```
count 357 : /graphql
```

If you have an idea.
Thanks

Comment: How do you count today?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere today, I count with the monitoring service on Google Cloud Platform with a request. A Request count on Cloud Run Revision ressource type. But with that, I have just the number for 200, 300, 400 code request. I don't have the exactly query, the exactly endpoint.

Comment: Here is some information that you requested: https://dev.to/davidoliveira/setup-hasura-at-google-cloud-run-42i8 "can I use Hasura Cloud service on my Hasura on Google Cloud Run"

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with GraphQL unfortunately. All queries are sent to the `/v1/graphql` endpoint on Hasura, and the only way to distinguish the operations is by parsing the `query` parameter of the HTTP request and grabbing the operation name.

If Google Cloud allows you to query properties in logs of HTTP requests, you can set up filters on the body, something like:

"Where `[request params].query` includes 'MyQueryName'"

Otherwise your two options are:

1. Use Hasura Cloud (https://hasura.io/cloud), which gives you a count of all operations and detailed metrics (response time, variables, etc) on your console dashboard
2. Write and deploy a custom middleware server or a script for a reverse proxy that handles this

Comment: Thank you for your help ! But can I use Hasura Cloud service on my Hasura on Google Cloud Run ?